# Livewire component event is not caught

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a catagory containing a collection of sheetitems and i'm trying to set an edit mode for a newly created sheetItem. I toggle this mode with alpine but i want to set the edit mode via a livewire component property also.

This is my delete component:

```
<div x-data="{showDeleteButton : false }" x-on:toggle-edit-mode-category-{{ 
$sheetItem->category->id }}.window="showDeleteButton = $event.detail.value">
    <div x-show="showDeleteButton | $wire.showDeleteButton" class="mt-1">
        <div wire:click="deleteSheetItem({{$sheetItem->id}})">
            @include('components.balance.buttons.delete-image')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see it is also visible on the following property:

```
$wire.showDeleteButton
```

So when i save an Item the following is triggered:

```
public function saveSheetItem()
{
    $sheetItem = new SheetItem;
    $sheetItem->name = $this->name;
    $sheetItem->amount = Item::convertEurosToEuroCents($this->amount);
    $sheetItem->category_id = $this->category->id;
    $sheetItem->balance_id = $this->balance->id;
    $sheetItem->save();

    $this->resetForm();
    $this->dispatch("sheet-item-saved", id: $sheetItem->id);
}
```

This triggers the update of my category ans thus my sheetitems in all categories ( planning on making that more specific also ). This triggers "sheet-item-saved". This triggers:

```
#[On('sheet-item-saved')]
#[On('sheet-item-deleted')]
#[On('updated-show-current-balance')]
public function updateCategory($id = null)
{
    $sheetItemService = new SheetItemService();
    $this->category = $sheetItemService->getCategoryWithSheetItems($this->category);
    $this->getCurrentBalance();

    $this->dispatch("sheet-item-created.{$id}");
}
```

The new Sheetitem is now created (it shows in the frondend) and another event is triggered to show the delete button for this sheetItem. This should be triggering:

```
 #[On("sheet-item-created.{sheetItem.id}")]
function showDeleteButton()
{
    Log::error($this->id());
    $this->showDeleteButton = true;
}
```

But this is not triggered i'm doing it according to the documentation of livewire 3. [Livewire Events](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/events)

Can anyone see why it is not triggering? I tried hardcoding it like so with an id i know exists. That does fire. Could it be that the component does not exist at the time the event is fired?:

```
 $this->dispatch("sheet-item-created.160");
 #[On("sheet-item-created.160")]
```

I have also tried logging the different events but that shows a correct order. I did some more logging and there simply isn't a listener present when the event is fired. Al sheetItem Components respond except for the newly created one.

Comment: To formulate an answer the class for delete component is required and moreover I suppose that the relevant code about the main component and its view would be useful. How do you display the rows? How do you display the delete component? For the moment I see that you are using a bitwise OR "|" instead of a logical OR "||" in the delete component: `<div x-show="showDeleteButton | $wire.showDeleteButton"`, also I have some doubts about using two variables to manage that x-show

Comment: Does my answer clarify this? Using onr variable instead of 2 was indeed part of the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result:
[image]

After some digging i fixed the issue. I did the following.

This is the view where the event is triggered and the sheetItem is generated. Notice ":show-delete-button="$sheetItem->showDeleteButton", This is a "modelable" property now.

```
<div x-data="{ ToggleEditMode : false }" id="{{ 'category-'.$category->id }}" class="card sheet-items-container">
<div class="flex justify-between card-sub-title">
    <span class="font-bold w-full flex justify-between">
        <div class="flex">
            <div>
                {{ $category->name }}
            </div>
            <div class="ml-3" x-on:click="$dispatch('toggle-edit-mode-category-{{ $category->id}}', {value: ToggleEditMode = !ToggleEditMode})">
                <div x-show="!ToggleEditMode">
                    <x-balance.buttons.edit-button x-show="ToggleEditMode" wire:click="showDeleteButtons"/>
                </div>
                <div x-show="ToggleEditMode" wire:click="updateCategory">
                    <x-balance.buttons.save-button/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div x-show="ToggleEditMode">
            @include('components.balance.buttons.delete-button-category')
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="sheet-items-list">
    @foreach($category->sheetItems as $sheetItem)
        <livewire:balance.sheet-items.sheet-item
            :sheet-item="$sheetItem"
            :show-delete-button="$sheetItem->showDeleteButton"
            :key="'sheet-item-'.$sheetItem->id"/>
    @endforeach
</div>
</div>
```

This is where the my delete component is included in " livewire:balance.sheet-items.sheet-item/":

```
<div x-bind:class="$wire.showCurrentBalance ? 'sheet-item-input-amount-income-day' : 'sheet-item-input-amount-no-income-day'"
     class="flex place-items-center">
    <div class="pt-1">&euro;</div>
    <x-input
        wire:model.live="amount"
        class="text-right"
        type="text"
    />
    <template x-if="!$wire.showCurrentBalance">
        <div class="ml-1">
            @include('components.balance.buttons.delete-button-sheet-item')
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
<template x-if="$wire.showCurrentBalance">
    <div class="flex flex-row-reverse">
        @include('components.balance.buttons.delete-button-sheet-item')
        <div>
            <div class="flex place-items-center justify-end">
                <div class="pt-1 mr-1">&euro;{{ $total }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my delete component, the key difference is that this changed from "showDeleteButton | $wire.showDeleteButton" to "$wire.showDeleteButton" and i changed it to:

```
x-on:toggle-edit-mode-category-{{ $sheetItem->category->id }}.window="$wire.showDeleteButton = $event.detail.value
```

So if i toggle it with alpine or set the property in my component the delete button will show:

```
<div x-data="{showDeleteButton : false }" x-on:toggle-edit-mode-category-{{ $sheetItem->category->id }}.window="$wire.showDeleteButton = $event.detail.value">
<div x-show="$wire.showDeleteButton" class="mt-1">
    <div wire:click="deleteSheetItem({{$sheetItem->id}})">
        @include('components.balance.buttons.delete-image')
    </div>
</div>
```

This happens in the following order. A new sheetItem is saved:

```
public function saveSheetItem()
{
    $sheetItem = new SheetItem;
    $sheetItem->name = $this->name;
    $sheetItem->amount = Item::convertEurosToEuroCents($this->amount);
    $sheetItem->category_id = $this->category->id;
    $sheetItem->balance_id = $this->balance->id;
    $sheetItem->save();

    $this->resetForm();
    $this->dispatch("sheet-item-saved." . $sheetItem->category->id, id: $sheetItem->id);
}
```

The event is caught and for some reason the item is present in the sheetitems collection, i set the "showDeleteButton" property wich is "modelable", and the delete button shows:

```
#[On('sheet-item-saved.{category.id}')]
function addSheetItemToCategory($id)
{
    $this->category->sheetItems->map(function ($sheetItem) use ($id) {
        if ($sheetItem->id === $id) {
            $sheetItem->showDeleteButton = true;
            $sheetItem->total = Item::convertEuroCentsToEuros($sheetItem->count * $sheetItem->amount);
            $sheetItem->amount = Item::convertEuroCentsToEuros($sheetItem->amount);
        }
        return $sheetItem;
    });
}
```

It's a bit of a long story but maybe someone is helped with it.

Comment: if i omit "#[Modelable]" for showDeleteButton it keep working